# sql script mssql express 2008 windows 2008 server R2 x64

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, scripting

Scenerio:I need to run an update sql script after another scheduled task.
server=Windows Server 2008 R2 x64
db = Sql Express 2008
when? - Everyday buy Sunday(i know how to do this)

Why? A third party exe is adding 1 in two columns where it needs to be null or blank. They will not modify their code to accommodate our requirements so I either have to do it manually(about 1100-1200 records) or run a sql script somehow.

What would be "best practice"? Batch file? vb script? and how do I do it? :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a windows job and [SQLCMD utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) to schedule and run your TSQL Script using something similar to this

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" - i"C:\Scripts\UpdateScript.sql"
```

You might also go for a paid solution($79) like this one http://www.valesoftware.com/products-express-agent.php